# Two of the Same UIView removefromsuperview error

Tags: ipad, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I'm trying to remove a UIView that is initialised when a button is clicked. I've clicked that button twice, so two of the same UIView appear. I can remove the first one no problem but when I try to do that same thing with the second of the same view nothing happens? I figure this is because it's a duplicate it doesn't register that it is there as it thinks its been removed...
Here is my code:

```
- (void)createStamp13 {
    //--EDIT--//
    stampV13Array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:3];
    [stampV13Array addObject:stampV13];

    stampV13 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 300, 172, 330)];
    //[firstPage addSubview:stampV13];
    [firstPage addSubview:(UIView*)[stampV13Array objectAtIndex:0];
    //--//
    stampV13.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    stampThirteen = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"exclaim_r.png"]];
    stampThirteen.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 172, 330);
    [stampV13 addSubview:stampThirteen];
}
```

that is the button function for when I create it. This is the remove function:

```
- (void)removeImage5:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"Delete StampV13");
    if (stampV13) {
    [self.stampV13 removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

I hope that what I explained makes sense, I'd appreciate any help! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`stampV13` is a single variable and can only point to one object at a time.  If you call `createStamp13` twice, the variable has lost track of the first object it pointed to.  To have multiple copies of these views, keep their references in an array instead of one variable and do whatever you need with all the array elements.

Some additional details:

- Add a property to your .h file such as `@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *stampV13Array;` and synthesize it.
- Initialize `stampV13Array` inside an 'init...' method for your class that contains the `createStamp13` code.  (Which exact method depends on how you crate objects of that class.)
- Change the first line of your `createStamp13` method to be `UIView *stampV13 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 300, 172, 330)];`.
- Add a line at the end of the method to put the view into the array: `[self.stampV13Array addObject:stampV13];`.

After that you'll need to reference members of the array wherever you used to use `stampV13`.

Comment: Cool thanks for putting me on the right track I'll give that a go!

Comment: I've tried several ways to attempt what you've said, but I'm not as familiar with NSArray/NSMutableArray as I thought... I was wondering if you might be able to give me an example of what you mean? so I might be able to work from there?

Comment: I've added some details about how I imagine it working.  If you still have problems, let me know what exactly they are and I'll see if I can explain better.

Comment: Thanks I'll have a go with what you've put. Thanks for your help!

Comment: By initialising it do you mean `stampV13Array = [NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"",nil];` or do you mean something different? I'm sorry I've not really used NSArray's before. I tried to look at the Documentation but I couldn't relate it to what i was trying to do. I'll edit the above code with what I've got.

Comment: I don't think you want the empty string in there.  I'd go with `self.stampV13Array = [NSMutableArray array];` unless you know a good number to use as a starting capacity.